# PHP Converting Text to Query

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting my Laravel application to be able to accept a text field, which then gets sent through to the controller. The text field would come through like this:

```
$message = "Hello, my name is [first_name], I like [thing]"
```

It then needs to be able to convert that statement to be able to insert the required fields:

```
$message2 = "Hello, my name is " . $first_name . ", I like " . $thing;
```

How would it be best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you can achieve it with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```php
$message = "Hello, my name is [first_name], I like [thing]";

$message2 = str_replace([
    "[first_name]",
    "[thing]"
], [
    $first_name,
    $thing
], $message);

echo $message2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an associative array of all the possible variables available you can iterate over them, and inject them into the string using str_replace like so :

```
$variables = array("first_name"=>"John","thing"=>"something");


foreach($variables as $key => $value){
   $string = str_replace('['.$key.']', $value, $string);
}
```